# Get jQuery dialog to work onlcik

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, dialog

I am trying to have an icon, when clicked, trigger a jQuery dialog box that displays message specific to the item being clicked. Since I'm new to jQuery, I'm having absolutely no luck. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Section of code from the ASP MVC View

```
    <td>
    @if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Notes))
    {
        <span id="notes" onclick='GetNotes(@id);'>
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/magnify.gif")" alt="Show Notes" />
        </span>           
    }

        <div id="@id" style="display:none;">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Notes)
        </div>       
    </td>
```

jQuery code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#thetable").tablesorter();
    }
    );

    function GetNotes(id) {
        $(function GetNotes() {
            $("#" + id + "\"").dialog();
        });
    }

</script>
```

EDIT

the onlick method name contained an error previously. There was an extra ')'.

Answer (score 2):

You have some pretty broken javascript within this `GetNotes` function. Try like this:

```
function GetNotes(id) {
    $('#' + id).dialog();
}
```

Also watch your javascript debugging console in the browser. It will show you the errors.

Comment: Thank you! I also had a typo ion the onlick call. There was an extra ')'

Comment: Yes, didn't notice that initially. Look at the js console. It will tell you everything.